# jquery click event to add/remove class to only one div, when several have the same classes

Tags: php, jquery, html, toggle, expand

I have a 'blog' page in which the blog posts are generated using php. The divs all have the same classes, PHP code below:

```
$loopResult .= ' 
            <div class="blogbox show"> 
                <div class="blogtitle">'.$row['TITLE'].'</div> 
                <div class="blogdate">'.$row['DATE'].'</div>                    
                <div class="blogcontent">'.$row['CONTENT'].'</div> 
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="'.$row['IMAGE'].'"/></div> 
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="'.$row['IMAGEB'].'"/></div>
                <div class="blogimage"> <img src="'.$row    ['IMAGEC'].'"/></div> 
                <div class="showHide">Show/Hide</div>
            </div>              
    '; 
} 
echo $loopResult;
```

I have a jquery click function on the showHide div that will toggle a class to expand the div for reading.
JQUERY:

```
$('.showHide').click(function() {
$('.blogbox').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Obviously, my issue is that the click function expands ALL of the blog posts, not just the one in which the user clicked.

How do I go about doing this so only the div selected is expanded? As you can see, I am relatively new to this so any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('.showHide').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.blogbox').toggleClass('show');
    });
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the speedy reply. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
$('.showHide').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
    });
```

Using the general class name `showHide` as the selector fpr the click event, but referring only to the actual element with `this` will do the trick for you.

Here's a fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/hhgxsnv1/

And with smoother effects you can also include the jQuery ui library:
http://jsfiddle.net/hhgxsnv1/2/

```
$('.showHide').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('show', 500, 'easeOutSine');
   });
```